# How can I check the version before installing a package using 'apt-get'?

Tags: debian, version, apt, apt-get, dpkg

I'm thinking to install *hylafax+* version 5.5.4 which was released last month on my [Debian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debian) PC.

I checked `dpkg -l | grep "hylafax"` and found out that the current version is 5.5.3. Then I checked `apt-cache search hylafax` and saw the packages are available, but I can't see any version number.

How can I find the version of packages available in the `apt-get`?

Comment: Same question on Unix & Linux Stack Exchange: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6284/check-package-version-using-apt-get-aptitude

Answer (score 397, accepted):

OK, I found it.

`apt-cache policy <package name>` will show the version details.

It also shows which version is currently installed and which versions are available to install.

For example, `apt-cache policy hylafax+`

Comment: Can't believe this isn't shown in `apt install`, to give you a chance to review the versions before saying `Y`.

Comment: If we use `apt install` some packages (may not installed) get install straightaway. So I think for new Linux user its better to use `apt policy`.

Comment: @BenMorel it actually is possible, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74348039/2388257).

Answer (score 51):

**`apt-cache policy <package-name>`**

```
$ apt-cache policy redis-server
redis-server:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 2:2.8.4-2
  Version table:
     2:2.8.4-2 0
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/universe amd64 Packages
```

**`apt-get install -s <package-name>`**

```
$ apt-get install -s redis-server
NOTE: This is only a simulation!
      apt-get needs root privileges for real execution.
      Keep also in mind that locking is deactivated,
      so don't depend on the relevance to the real current situation!
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  libjemalloc1 redis-tools
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libjemalloc1 redis-server redis-tools
0 upgraded, 3 newly installed, 0 to remove and 3 not upgraded.
Inst libjemalloc1 (3.5.1-2 Ubuntu:14.04/trusty [amd64])
Inst redis-tools (2:2.8.4-2 Ubuntu:14.04/trusty [amd64])
Inst redis-server (2:2.8.4-2 Ubuntu:14.04/trusty [amd64])
Conf libjemalloc1 (3.5.1-2 Ubuntu:14.04/trusty [amd64])
Conf redis-tools (2:2.8.4-2 Ubuntu:14.04/trusty [amd64])
Conf redis-server (2:2.8.4-2 Ubuntu:14.04/trusty [amd64])
```

**`apt-cache show <package-name>`**

```
$ apt-cache show redis-server
Package: redis-server
Priority: optional
Section: universe/misc
Installed-Size: 744
Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com>
Original-Maintainer: Chris Lamb <lamby@debian.org>
Architecture: amd64
Source: redis
Version: 2:2.8.4-2
Depends: libc6 (>= 2.14), libjemalloc1 (>= 2.1.1), redis-tools (= 2:2.8.4-2), adduser
Filename: pool/universe/r/redis/redis-server_2.8.4-2_amd64.deb
Size: 267446
MD5sum: 066f3ce93331b876b691df69d11b7e36
SHA1: f7ffbf228cc10aa6ff23ecc16f8c744928d7782e
SHA256: 2d273574f134dc0d8d10d41b5eab54114dfcf8b716bad4e6d04ad8452fe1627d
Description-en: Persistent key-value database with network interface
 Redis is a key-value database in a similar vein to memcache but the dataset
 is non-volatile. Redis additionally provides native support for atomically
 manipulating and querying data structures such as lists and sets.
 .
 The dataset is stored entirely in memory and periodically flushed to disk.
Description-md5: 9160ed1405585ab844f8750a9305d33f
Homepage: http://redis.io/
Bugs: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+filebug
Origin: Ubunt
```

**`dpkg -l <package-name>`**

```
$ dpkg -l nginx
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name                                     Version                   Architecture              Description
+++-========================================-=========================-=========================-=====================================================================================
ii  nginx                                    1.6.2-1~trusty            amd64                     high performance web server
```

Comment: Note that `dpkg -l` only lists the installed packages. Not useful to see the version in advance.

Comment: Thanks for the -s flag in apt-get install! :)

Answer (score 14):

```
apt policy <package>
```

for short

Answer (score 12):

Linux Mint, Debian 9, Ubuntu 16.04 and older:

**Short info**:

```
apt policy <package_name>
```

**Detailed info** (With Description and Depends):

```
apt show <package_name>
```

Answer (score 7):

The following might work well enough:

```
aptitude versions ^hylafax+
```

See more in [aptitude(8)](http://manpages.debian.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=aptitude&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=Debian%20testing%20jessie&format=html&locale=en)

Answer (score 7):

You can also just simply do the regular **`apt-get update`** and then, as per the manual, do:

**`apt-get -V upgrade`**

> -V  Show verbose version numbers

Which will show you the current package vs the one which will be upgraded in a format similar to the one bellow:

```
~# sudo apt-get -V upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages will be upgraded:
   curl (7.38.0-4+deb8u14 => 7.38.0-4+deb8u15)
   php5 (5.6.40+dfsg-0+deb8u2 => 5.6.40+dfsg-0+deb8u3)
2 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 12.0 MB of archives.
After this operation, 567 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
```

Comment: This is much better than the accepted answer if you want to update your system and review all the version changes in one go, instead of invoking `apt-cache policy` _on every package_

Answer (score 5):

on debian :

```
apt list --upgradable
```

gives the list with package, version to be upgraded, and actual version of the package.

result :

```
base-files/stable 8+deb8u8 amd64 [upgradable from: 8+deb8u7]
bind9-host/stable 1:9.9.5.dfsg-9+deb8u11 amd64 [upgradable from: 1:9.9.5.dfsg-9+deb8u9]
ca-certificates/stable 20141019+deb8u3 all [upgradable from: 20141019+deb8u2]
certbot/jessie-backports 0.10.2-1~bpo8+1 all [upgradable from: 0.8.1-2~bpo8+1]
dnsutils/stable 1:9.9.5.dfsg-9+deb8u11 amd64 [upgradable from: 1:9.9.5.dfsg-9+deb8u9]
```

Comment: Great answer! Gives overview for all packages, no additional packages (like `apt-show-versions`) needed.

Answer (score 4):

Also, the **apt-show-versions** package (installed separately) parses dpkg information about what is installed and tells you if packages are up to date.

Example...

```
sudo apt-show-versions --regex chrome
```

Output:

```
google-chrome-stable/stable upgradeable from 32.0.1700.102-1 to 35.0.1916.114-1
xserver-xorg-video-openchrome/quantal-security uptodate 1:0.3.1-0ubuntu1.12.10.1
```

Answer (score 2):

Also, according to the man page:

```
apt-cache showpkg <package_name>
```

can also be used to:

> ...display information about the packages listed on the command line. Remaining arguments are package
> names. The available versions and reverse dependencies of each package listed are listed, as well as forward
> dependencies for each version. Forward (normal) dependencies are those packages upon which the package in
> question depends; reverse dependencies are those packages that depend upon the package in question. Thus,
> forward dependencies must be satisfied for a package, but reverse dependencies need not be.

Example:

```
apt-cache policy conky

conky:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1.10.3-1
  Version table:
     1.10.3-1 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu yakkety/universe amd64 Packages
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu yakkety/universe i386 Packages
```

Answer (score 1):

As posted somewhere else, this works, too:

`apt-cache madison <package_name>`

Comment: What is "madison"? Can you explain it in your answer? (But ***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the question/answer should appear as if it was written today.)

Comment: @PeterMortensen: if you care to run `man apt-cache` you will find your answer, but if you are too busy, here it is from the man page:
>>
madison pkg...
           apt-cache's madison command attempts to mimic the output format and a subset of the functionality of the Debian archive management tool, madison. It displays available
           versions of a package in a tabular format. Unlike the original madison, it can only display information for the architecture for which APT has retrieved package lists
           (APT::Architecture).

Answer (score 1):

Use a `-V` option when installing through either of `apt-get` or `apt`. You can make an `alias apt="apt -V"` to avoid entering it manually every time.

Example:

```hs
# apt -V install podman
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
   aardvark-dns (1.2.0-0ubuntu22.04+obs28.7)
   catatonit (0.1.7-1)
   conmon (2:2.1.4-0ubuntu22.04+obs13.12)
   containers-common (4:1-0ubuntu22.04+obs16.8)
   criu (3.16.1-2)
   crun (1.6-0ubuntu22.04+obs46.9)
   fuse-overlayfs (1.9-0ubuntu22.04+obs18.9)
   libnet1 (1.1.6+dfsg-3.1build3)
   libprotobuf-c1 (1.3.3-1ubuntu2.1)
   libprotobuf23 (3.12.4-1ubuntu7)
   libslirp0 (4.6.1-1build1)
   libyajl2 (2.1.0-3build2)
   netavark (1.2.0-0ubuntu22.04+obs21.7)
   podman-gvproxy (4:4.3.0-0ubuntu22.04+obs63.8)
   python3-protobuf (3.12.4-1ubuntu7)
   slirp4netns (1.2.0-0ubuntu22.04+obs10.11)
   uidmap (1:4.8.1-2ubuntu2)
Suggested packages:
   qemu-user-static (1:6.2+dfsg-2ubuntu6.5)
The following NEW packages will be installed:
   aardvark-dns (1.2.0-0ubuntu22.04+obs28.7)
   catatonit (0.1.7-1)
   conmon (2:2.1.4-0ubuntu22.04+obs13.12)
   containers-common (4:1-0ubuntu22.04+obs16.8)
   criu (3.16.1-2)
   crun (1.6-0ubuntu22.04+obs46.9)
   fuse-overlayfs (1.9-0ubuntu22.04+obs18.9)
   libnet1 (1.1.6+dfsg-3.1build3)
   libprotobuf-c1 (1.3.3-1ubuntu2.1)
   libprotobuf23 (3.12.4-1ubuntu7)
   libslirp0 (4.6.1-1build1)
   libyajl2 (2.1.0-3build2)
   netavark (1.2.0-0ubuntu22.04+obs21.7)
   podman (4:4.3.0-0ubuntu22.04+obs63.8)
   podman-gvproxy (4:4.3.0-0ubuntu22.04+obs63.8)
   python3-protobuf (3.12.4-1ubuntu7)
   slirp4netns (1.2.0-0ubuntu22.04+obs10.11)
   uidmap (1:4.8.1-2ubuntu2)
0 upgraded, 18 newly installed, 0 to remove and 40 not upgraded.
Need to get 41.5 MB of archives.
After this operation, 125 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
```