# How can I learn ubunu postgresql version as default?

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu

When I install the ubuntu server, the postgresql repository package names are installed on server automatically. So when I type command `sudo apt-get install postgresql` it will start installation. But which version will be installed? I don't know it.

So how can I learn which version will be installed?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Which version of PostgreSQL am I running?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13733719/which-version-of-postgresql-am-i-running) or maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18885820/how-to-check-the-version-before-install-packages-using-apt-get?

Comment: `apt-cache policy postgresql`

Comment: @zerkms thank for answer. I run command `apt-cache policy postgresql` and response is like this `9.5+173ubuntu0.2` But minor version does not write like 9.5.14

Comment: @OcasoProtal I want to learn which version of Postgresql will be installed from apt cache. Bu your solution is to learn Postgresql version after installed.

Comment: @barteloma Did you even check the second link?

Comment: @melpomene checked now, thanks. But my question marked as duplicate using wrong link.

Comment: You can also `apt-cache show`. If neither has that information - then it's impossible to obtain it from elsewhere.

Comment: @barteloma Yeah, I misunderstood your question first, sorry. That's why I added the second link. Either way there is already a solution for your question ;)